# Is it possible to add a web application to the Android marketplace?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to add a web-based application to the Android market. Is this possible? Tools like JQueryMobile and JTouch are great, but it's easy to miss user acquisition opportunities if you don't get into the marketplace.

You see examples of this from Google - "Tasks", "Latitude" for example. But I haven't found a resource explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not create an app that simply launches the web page as an intent?

EDIT:

I just found this as well:

http://androinica.com/2011/01/21/appsgeyser-lets-you-easily-convert-any-web-content-to-an-android-app/

It seems to do what you need.

Comment: its one line of code. simply write this on your onCreate of the activity. startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" ) ) );

Comment: sounds like the bottom line is that it can't be done. but that's ok. i'm going to experiment with building an android app shell. thanks.

Comment: you've offered (a perfectly reasonable) workaround, but the question was actually "can a web-based app be added to the market?" from my understanding, the answer is "no". but i'm experimenting with the method you've described. i'll circle back.

Answer (score 0):

Create an app that contains a button that ends up linking to your site and having the app create a browser instance. Look at "Adobe Flash Showcase" app. There are a few apps that are in the store that are just "bookmarks" to their site. As far as I know though couldn't you create a WebView instance and have it use that inside of the app.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html